# Declare a PCL point cloud in QT object class

Tags: c++, qt, point-cloud-library

I'm new from using the PCL (Point Cloud Library). I try to declare a point cloud in QT object class in private, like this:

```
class pcl_sys : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit pcl_sys();
    ~pcl_sys();
    void stop();
    bool load_pcd_file(int type);

signals:

public slots:

protected:
    void run();

private:
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr *cloud_test;

};
```

Then I new the point cloud when I opened up the program:

```
pcl_sys::pcl_sys()
{
     cloud_test=0;
     cloud_test= new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
}
```

but when i try to clear the points when I try to load a file, QT give me an error shows that points is not belong to template cloud_test.

```
bool pcl_sys::load_pcd_file(int choice)
{

     cloud_test->points.clear();
}
```

How do I fix this issue? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

he cloud_test is a pointer to a PointCloud::Ptr type. So you have to access to its body using function get() and then access the points through it.

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr *cloud_test; 
cloud_test= new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>); 
if (!cloud_test) cloud_test->get()->points.clear();
```

you can use this either. in the below, cloud_test is a PointCloud::Ptr type (not a reference pointer):

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud_test  ;
cloud_test = pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
cloud_test.get()->points.clear();
```

or you can use boost::shared_ptr as pointer to PointCloud::Ptr type as below:

```
boost::shared_ptr<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr> cloud_test; 
cloud_test = boost::make_shared <pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr> (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
cloud_test->get()->points.clear();
```

:)

Comment: One more question, thanks. it works for `points.clear();` Bit I'm a bit screwed up. I can't load files now. `pcl::io::loadPCDFile(fileName.toStdString(), cloud_test->get()->Ptr)`

Comment: pay attention to conversions, if you have used `pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud_test;` then you should use the function like this: `pcl::io::loadPCDFile("o.pcd", *(cloud_test->get()));`

Comment: Thanks. I'm kind of screwed up with these types.

Comment: yeah, they blow my head off! :)

Answer (score 0):

Just do `cloud_test = new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>` instead of creating a new pointer to a `PointCloud`.

Comment: If I change the declaration and new the point cloud to `pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>`, I'm not able to load any PCD files cause QT won't accept `cloud_test->Ptr`

Comment: Do you mean I change `cloud_test= new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);` to `cloud_test = new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>`? It's not working, I'm using QT 5.2.1 and PCL 1.6.0