# How to cast shared_ptr<Foo<Derived> > to shared_ptr<Foo<Base> >?

Tags: c++, boost, c++11

I need to cast `shared_ptr<Foo<Derived> >` to `shared_ptr<Foo<Base> >` but does not know how to. Basically I wanna do:

```
shared_ptr<Foo<Base>> p (new Foo<Derived>());
```

But the compiler gives error:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/shared_ptr_base.h: In instantiation of 'std::__shared_ptr<_Tp, _Lp>::__shared_ptr(_Tp1*) [with _Tp1 = Foo<Derived> _Tp = Foo<Base> __gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy _Lp = (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2u]':
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/shared_ptr.h:113:32:   required from 'std::shared_ptr<_Tp>::shared_ptr(_Tp1*) [with _Tp1 = Foo<Derived> _Tp = Foo<Base>]'
main.cpp:17:48:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:768:39: error: cannot convert 'Foo<Derived>*' to 'Foo<Base>*' in initialization
         : _M_ptr(__p), _M_refcount(__p)
```

[Test Code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9eeb3a684ed05f9f)

Comment: In general this can't be done because `Foo<Base>` and `Foo<Derived>` are unrelated types. If you want better advice, you'll have to explain what `Foo` is actually supposed to do.

Comment: Because a `Foo<T>` doesn't derive from a `Foo<U>`.

Comment: @BrianBi Relavant questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22209367/use-cloudviewer-with-custom-pointt-type although no one answered it so I put it in a simpler way as above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A class template with a different parameter is considered by the C++ type system to be an entirely different type.

```
Foo<Base>
```

is not the same type as a

```
Foo<Derived>
```

and there is no polymorphic relation between them.

Comment: although I cannot find appropriate quote in C++ Standard

Comment: that would be hard, as why would it mention things that are not related?  It describes things that are related, not everything that is not!

Comment: @Yakk in each topic that Standard covers Standard introduces many examples of legal things as well as things absolutely illegal. Looking for example covering this topic under Templates is sensible thing, as many of us might think initially that such conversion is possible.

Comment: It is always possible to *define* a specialization `template<> struct Foo<Derived> : Foo<Base> ...` depending on what `Foo` actually does. However, the last time I did this, playing around with an entire class hierarchy like that was such a headache (it was impossible to keep track of relations without writing them down) that I decided to avoid it in the future.

Comment: So, there is a way to solve the OP's problem: specialize `shared_ptr`.  On a scale of 1 to overkill, it is overkill.